# Error(s) trying to define a one-to-many relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to define a one-to-many relationship in laravel where I have a `Movimentacao` class and a `TipoMovimentacaoFin`. One `Movimentacao` **is one** type `TipoMovimentacaoFin` and a `TipoMovimentacaoFin` **can have many** `Movimentacao`(s) associated with it. For it, in their models I declared:

```
class Movimentacao extends Model
{
public $timestamps = false;

public function tipo(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Patropi\TipoMovimentacaoFin', 'tipo', 'tipo');
 }
}
```

and

```
class TipoMovimentacaoFin extends Model
{
public $timestamps = false;

public function movimentacaos(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Movimentacao', 'id', 'tipo');

  }
}
```

At the database level I got:

tipo_movimentacao_fins.tipo (varchar) as PK plus other columns and movimentacaos.tipo as FK to the first table. The names of the tables were auto generated by Laravel standards. The migrations for the tables are:

```
Schema::create('tipo_movimentacao_fins', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('tipo', 50);
        $table->char('relacionado_empresa', 1);
        $table->char('entrada_saida', 1);
        $table->primary('tipo');
    });

Schema::create('movimentacaos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->float('montante', 12, 2);
        $table->dateTime('data_prevista');
        $table->dateTime('data_vencimento')->nullable();
        $table->char('esta_pago', 1);
        $table->float('juros', 6, 2)->nullable();
        $table->smallInteger('periodo_juros')->nullable();
        $table->string('tipo', 50);
        $table->string('referente_a', 255);
        $table->string('obs', 255)->nullable();

        $table->foreign('tipo')->references('tipo')->on('tipo_movimentacao_fins');
    });
```

Now the problems begins in the View when I'm trying to access the type (tipo) of the `Movimentacao`. I give to the view the collections with `$movimentacaos = Movimentacao::with('tipo')->orderBy('data_prevista', 'desc')->get()` and when I loop `@foreach($movimentacaos as $mov)` if I access `$mov->tipo` I get the value of movimentacaos.tipo column and that's as expected. If I try to access some column of the `tipo_movimentacao_fins` for a given `$mov` I can't:

```
{{ $mov->tipo()->relacionado_empresa }}
```

Gives **Undefined property** error. So, since the documentation of laravel is kinda messy, I'm trying to analyse what's the return of the `->tipo()` call and more errors occurs:

If I just write `{{ $mov->tipo() }}` it gives me the error "**htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given**".

If `{!! $mov->tipo() !!}` gives "**Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo could not be converted to string**".

If `{{ var_export($mov->tipo()) }}` gives "**var_export does not handle circular references**".

Finally, if I try a var_dump it gives **Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 98582528 bytes)**

Also the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) didn't helped too much in regards of how to access the BelongsTo Object instance.;

**EDIT** I edited the code as recommended in the answers and comments but the same problems persists.

Comment: Maybe you need to use id: return $this->hasOne('App\TipoMovimentacaoFin', 'tipo', 'id');

Answer (score 0):

It should be belongsTo relationship with correct FK definition:

```
public function tipo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TipoMovimentacaoFin', 'tipo');
}
```

And another relationship should look like:

```
public function movimentacaos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Movimentacao', 'tipo');
}
```

This will work if `tipo` is in the `movimentacaos` table and points to `id` in the `tipomovimentacaofins` table.

Comment: `return $this->hasMany('App\Movimentacao', 'tipo',);` should be `return $this->hasMany('App\Movimentacao', 'tipo');`. There is a comma that will raise an error

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship is bad. Should be:

```
class Movimentacao extends Model
{
public $timestamps = false;

public function tipo(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TipoMovimentacaoFin', 'tipo');
 }
}
```

and:

```
class TipoMovimentacaoFin extends Model
{
public $timestamps = false;

public function movimentacaos(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Movimentacao', 'tipo');
  }
}
```

Please take a look at the [DOCs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still have the same errors

Comment: @Kyonhiss Is because when you query the data you dont use the relation. `$movimentacaos = Movimentacao::orderBy('data_prevista', 'desc')->get()` should be `$movimentacaos = Movimentacao::with('tipo')->orderBy('data_prevista', 'desc')->get()`

Comment: also didn't worked. I'll edit my OP to post more details of my code